# How to refer a function variable as a parameter of another function?

Tags: python, function, parameters, refer

I want to write a function (`function_A`) to optimize the parameters of a another function (`function_B`) through iteration. The function whose parameters to be optimized is:

```
 def function_B(a=10, b=12, c=14, d= 18):
    value = (...)
    return value
```

Now I want to find the combinations of parameter `a`,`b`,`c`,`d` that would optimize the results based on certain criteria. So I write the following function - for example - user can specify which parameter to optimize, in this case, we choose to optimize parameter `a`:

```
def function_A(variable = a, min = 10, max = 20):

    value = np.zeros((max - min + 1)) # initialize an empty vector to store results
    count = 0

    for i in np.linspace(1, 20, 20, endpoint=True):
        ans = function_B(variable = i)
        value[count] = ans
        count = count + 1

    return value
```

The problem is, I don't know how to specify `a` in `function_A`. I tried to use:

`function_A(variable = a, ...)`

`function_A(variable = 'a', ...)`

but neither works...how to specify `'a'` is the parameter I want to iterate through?

Answer (score 1):

Here is a very simplified example:

```
def A(a=5, b=4):
    return a, b

def B(var):
    x = {var:'numberyouwant'}
    return A(**x)
```

So in your case pass the variable as string and pass this into a dictonary and finally using keyworded variable update your function with the paremeter you want to optimize.

```
def function_A(variable = 'a', min = 10, max = 20):

    value = np.zeros((max - min + 1)) # initialize an empty vector to store results
    count = 0

    for i in np.linspace(1, 20, 20, endpoint=True):
        temp_dict = {variable: i}
        ans = function_B(**temp_dict)
        value[count] = ans
        count = count + 1

return value
```

Comment: Thanks, but I still don't quite understand..I tried the following code as a simple example, and got error msg. could you show me where I got wrong?

Comment: `def A(a = 1, b = 2):
    return a+b` and 
`def B(var = 'a', min = 10):
    temp_dict = {var:min}
    ans = A(var)
    return ans` then I test it `B(var = 'b')` and got error msg _TypeError: cannot concatenate 'str' and 'int' objects_